# Why picture move away?

Tags: graphics

I am using texlive2014.But When i import a picture,it just move away.

This is my source code:

```
\usepackage{graphics}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ProjectStartWorkflow.jpg}
    \caption{项目启动流程}
\end{figure}
```

My compiler is xelatex.The picture move to next page,i can not understand where i am going wrong?

Comment: Not enough info, I guess. It's better if you post a minimal compilable example, that we can compile at home to reproduce exactly your problem (may be that includes linking the image, or anything that lets us reproduce the error).

Comment: The `figure` environment is _just_ to allow latex to move the figure to help with page breaking. It is `\includegraphics` that actually includes the image, so you are not doing anything wrong that is the intended behaviour.

Comment: `figures` are floats and LaTeX place floats where they should be  which, not always, is where you want.

Comment: It seems that you read Chinese. Check this: http://www.zhihu.com/question/25082703/answer/30038248